# Codeception, code coverage и статичные классы

Tags: php, юнит-тесты, phpunit, codeception, code-coverage

Предположим, есть [такой](https://github.com/apicycle/common/blob/a7828544d9d7466b7af491bcaab567d1bdbc8f92/src/Utility/Transport/Http/HeaderNameNormalizer.php) класс и [такой](https://github.com/apicycle/common/blob/a7828544d9d7466b7af491bcaab567d1bdbc8f92/tests/Unit/Utility/Transport/Http/HeaderNameNormalizerTest.php) тест к нему. Я хочу, чтобы результаты этого теста записывались в code coverage, однако этого не происходит, даже если я явно прописываю `@covers`/ `@coversDefaultClass` + `@covers` - Codeception рапортует о нуле отковеренных методов. ЧЯДНТ?

p.s. для воспроизведения на локальной машине:

```
git clone https://github.com/apicycle/common.git apicycle-common && cd apicycle-common
git checkout a7828544d9
composer install
vendor/bin/codecept run --coverage --coverage-xml --coverage-html
```

Comment: Все, что относится к вопросу, должно быть **в самом вопросе**. Ссылки могут служить только _дополнением_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я добавил в codeception.yml всего 2 строчки:

```
coverage:
    enabled: true
```

и о чудо! заработало! )))

А вообще полезно доки читать, например, про [Code Coverage в Codeception](https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/2.0/docs/11-Codecoverage.md) (особенно про конфигурацию)